# Error in reading .rec file- (Input string was not in a correct format) and how to read from one line to another from text file

Tags: c#

I have a (*.rec) file which is including in this format:

```
1 0 0.123413
1 1 0.23423413
1 2 0.2234413
2 0 0.7456413
2 1 0.987651
2 2 0.0358413
3 0 0.4876513
3 1 0.986443
3 2 0.3465413
```

I wrote an script in C# to read it and save it in a text file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace _2test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;
            double[,] a = new double[1143599, 100];
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\1.rec");
            for (int x = 8935906; x <= 123295910; x++)
            {
              line = file.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(' ');
                int i=0;
                int j=0;
                foreach(string value in values)
                {
                    i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                    j = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                    a[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
                }

                var valuess = a.OfType<double>();
                using (var filestream = new FileStream("1000.txt", FileMode.Create))
                using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
                {
                    foreach (double value in values)
                        streamwriter.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it shows  error "Input string was not in a correct format" in line         `i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);` ??   while I am sure about the format of the data. And the next question is how can I start to read the file from a line until another line of file (I wanna read it from line 8935906 until line 123295910 and I am not sure that by doing `(int x = 8935906; x <= 123295910; x++)` can i achieve to my goal??

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `values[0]` when you debug it? It could be white space?

Comment: @SonerGönül Sorry I couldn't get what you mean? If you mean what is the type of data in valuse[0]? It's integer

Comment: no Soner is asking about the value of `values[0]`, you can debug and see.

Comment: No, the format is exactly like what i wrote above

Comment: Your code looks unnecessarily complex, have you looked at the `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` method?

Comment: @SonerGönül. the value  is "MyMediaLite.Ite.NveD". I think my code tries to read from the first line cause "MyMediaLite.Ite.NveD" is in the first line. how can i start from the 3 line?

Answer (score 0):

From your Comments : if you want to read from 3rd Line

before the loop you can call the `ReadLine()` method and ignore it for 2 times, so that next time when you start reading from for loop it starts from 3rd line.

Try This:

```
   file.ReadLine();  //read first line
   file.ReadLine();  //read second line

   for (int x = 8935906; x <= 123295910; x++)
   {
      line = file.ReadLine(); //read third line
      ...
   }
```